# Fetching the weather data of the place and set in flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, location, react-native-flatlist

I'm new in react native i'm making a dummy project on fetching the weather of the place in flatlist. I downloaded one project from github But i'm getting blank screen in my real device and emulator as well the link for the github repository is:-
https://github.com/andrewsmith1996/geolocationWeatherReactNative 
Any help will we appriciated

Comment: Please add the things you tried.

Comment: first there was an error "unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server"

Comment: Then i Added this dependency react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

Comment: then i get blank screen and also i added the fine location in manifest.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Did you tried this guide https://dev.to/andrewsmith1996/how-to-build-an-geolocation-weather-forecast-app-in-react-native-in-30-minutes-1kmo?

Comment: yes i tried this guide i downloaded the code from github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add this to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Second in the URL you have to add your access key

```
let url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' + this.state.latitude + '&lon=' + this.state.longitude + '&units=metric&appid=YOUR_KEY_HERE';
```

if you don't have the key then for this example to work use this url.

```
let url = 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22';
```

You will get something like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/u250N.png

Comment: where i have to add the URL?

Comment: In getWeather() function

Comment: How can i get key i don't known can you please provide the link

Comment: if i want to choose another city like mohali punjab

Comment: then how can i change it in api.

Comment: Use this:--
https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Mohali,in&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22